# Restful wcf Service error 'Unable to deserialize XML body with root name

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I have written a  RESFful service for a phone app.
I am not sure what am I doing wrong? I tried to test it with multiple content type settings but no luck.
The data from a phone app is coming encoded in following format.
PHNhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlIHhtbG5zOnNhbWxwPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6cHJvdG9jb2wiPjxzYW1scDpTdGF0dXM+PHNhbWxwOlN0YXR1c0NvZGU+ aGVyVmFsdWU+PC94ZW5jOkNpcGhlckRhdGE+PC94ZW5jOkVuY3J5cHRlZERhdGE+PC9zYW1sOkVuY3J5cHRlZEFzc2VydGlvbj48L3NhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlPg==";

This is the definition in the interface:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke]
    String GetUserInfo(String authenticateRequest);
```

I get error:  with following  test code.

'Unable to deserialize XML body with root name 'Binary' and root namespace '' (for operation 'GetMobileCheckCapture' and contract ('IMobileCC',  'http://tempuri.org/')) using DataContractSerializer

This is how I am trying to test the service:
String encryptedSAML =

PHNhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlIHhtbG5zOnNhbWxwPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6cHJvdG9jb2wiPjxzYW1scDpTdGF0dXM+PHNhbWxwOlN0YXR1c0NvZGU+ aGVyVmFsdWU+PC94ZW5jOkNpcGhlckRhdGE+PC94ZW5jOkVuY3J5cHRlZERhdGE+PC9zYW1sOkVuY3J5cHRlZEFzc2VydGlvbj48L3NhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlPg==";

```
 HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Services/Mservice.svc/GetUserInfo") as HttpWebRequest;
            req.KeepAlive = false;
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
              ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] bDataToPass = encoding.GetBytes(encryptedSAML);
            req.ContentLength = bDataToPass.Length;

        using (Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(bDataToPass, 0, bDataToPass.Length);
        }

        try
        {
            using (WebResponse webresponse = req.GetResponse())
            {
                StreamReader reader = null;
                string responses = "";

                string StatusDescription = ((HttpWebResponse)webresponse).StatusDescription;

                if (((HttpWebResponse)webresponse).StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    // Console.Write();
                }
                reader = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream());
                responses = reader.ReadToEnd();
                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmldoc.LoadXml(responses.Replace("&", "&amp;"));
                response = xmldoc;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            using (WebResponse response2 = e.Response)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response2;
                Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                using (Stream data = response2.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That string looks Base64 encoded.

Comment: Yes that is correct but Parameter is expected in this format I do decoding in the processing at wcf level but I am not able to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use UTF-8 encoding instead of ASCII?

```
 HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Services/Mservice.svc/GetUserInfo") as HttpWebRequest;
            req.KeepAlive = false;
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
              UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] bDataToPass = encoding.GetBytes(encryptedSAML);
            req.ContentLength = bDataToPass.Length;
```